# SSISTester with FakeSource gives error

Tags: unit-testing, ssis, ssistester

while using FakeSource with SSISTester. it gives error

```
[Id]: -1071636458
[Name]: -1071636458
[Source]: DFT-Process dimpt
[Description]: Cannot find input column with lineage ID "368" which is needed by "DC-Convert Data Types.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[PatientInOutStatus]". Check SourceInputColumnLineageID custom property of the output column.
```

any idea what did i miss?

Comment: We also are having this issue. Were you able to find a resolution? We found that altering the Function data transformations in the Package changed the error, and removing functions on SQL columns removed the issue entirely (but also, the desired functionality).

Answer (score 0):

In communication with BytesOfTwo, we discovered that this is a bug in their software. They recently released a patch to cover this behavior, [version 3.0.0.236](http://www.bytesoftwo.com/download.html).

> Release notes:
>
> - support for SQL SERVER 2016
> - extended support for complex scenarios where a package is executed by a script task from another package.
> - ignoring repositories, packages and executables when calculating
>   coverage. Examples in App.config.
> - ordering execution of unit tests. See ExecutionOrderFactor property of UnitTestAttribute.
> - fakesource, fakedestination and datatap are fully supported when targeting
>   executables
> - bug fix 1: AddPackageParameter supports object for value
>   and not only strings
> - bug fix 2: FakeSource fix when faking different data types (e.g. nvarchar). All data types work as designed and no errors are thrown.
> - added examples for bug-fix 2.
> - code optimizations